# Bring...Into Action

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the usage of the transitive phrase "***bring... into action***" in this [news article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/onthefrontline/2071842/Chinook-fleet-sitting-idle-costs-422m.html):

> The eight Mk3 helicopters, which have never flown, cost £32 million each. They were designed to be used by Special Forces but were never ***brought into action*** because of concerns about their safety.

I cannot find the phrase "***bring...into action***" in dictionaries.  According to this [dictionary definition](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/action), intransitive phrases like:

> --leap into action
>   --spring into action
>   --swing into action

are more common.

So, is the "***bring...into action***" pattern in the new article wrong?

Comment: No, it is not wrong.

Comment: When you use Google ngram to search for a phrase there will be links to attestations at the bottom of the results page. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22brought%20into%20action%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 1):

"Bring into action" is not a set phrase, it is just literal with "bring" meaning "cause, result in a state or condition":

​[Bring](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bring):

> - ***to cause, result in, or produce a state or condition:***
>
>   - *Bring the water to the boil (= make it start boiling).
>       She suddenly brought the interview to an end.
>       Her tragic story brought tears to my eyes (= made me cry).
>       What will the future bring for these refugees?*

(Cambridge Dictionary)